# How to create a unique key for two words?

Tags: java, algorithm, chat

I'm creating a chat application. I want to save conversations in different XML files. I'm thinking about generating a unique key for two names (Sender and receiver) and save the XML file with that key as a file name.
Is there an algorithm to generate that kind of key?
I thought of combining two words as a key. But I want to know the best practice.
**UPDATE**
I want to get the same key another time for same two users.

Comment: Why not include the two names along with the timestamp to create unique I'd?

Comment: @VishalKamat They don't want the timestamp included because they want messages with the same sender and receiver to be stored in the same file. Each file is a conversation between 2 users.

Comment: Do you just want to generate a unique file name, or do you want to be able to reconstruct the file name from a pair of words later on? What about the other way: Getting the original words from the file name?

Comment: Confused: Why do you call it a unique key? You already suggested yourself to simply combine (concatenate) the two names to make up a file name, so just do that. Since a chat is a two-way conversation, there is no "sender" and "receiver", just two names, so just put the lexicographically first name first, e.g. Mary is chatting with John, so file name is `John_Mary.xml`.

Comment: @tobias_k No I don't want to get original words from the file name.

Comment: @Andreas What about Mary_John.xml? (When sender and receiver interchanged)

Comment: @LasithaYapa That's why I said to put John before Mary, since John sorts before Mary lexicographically, i.e. like in an book index.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot just concatenate the two words as the key. Lets assume that users with name *1234* and *5678* were chatting, that would give the key *12345678*. But what if *12345* and *678* where chatting? That would give the same key!

So what's usually done is to add something between that should not occur in the two things you want to combine. Maybe some special characters that aren't allowed in the names. Even better would be to use the user's *ID*, as it probably wont change over time, and it often only contain numbers.

So if the examples above were userIds, you could add a separator with some letters between them (which works well for file names). For instance just an underscore *_*. Now the keys would be *1234_5678* and *12345_678*, so they can be distinguished.

Since you now have added the requirement that two users always should generate the same key, you could order the two values first. So *1234* sending to *5678* should give the same result as *5678* sending to *1234*.

Comment: @Arjan as I said, the separator should be something that cannot occur in the original keys. So if they can contain underscore, a different separator should be used.

Answer (score 0):

This will create a filename.xml for two usernames. If you switch the order of the usernames, the results will be the same.  The usernames are turned into two sha256 hex strings.  Those strings are joined, the return value is a sha256 hex string of that join.  No collisions have been found in sha256 yet, so you may assume it'll yield a unique filename. The filename will be lenghty, 64 characters.

This solution works for overlapping usernames, like ("123", "456") and ("1234", "56"), and any character is allowed in the username.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class TestStackOverflowQuestion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println(makeXmlFileName("Mary", "John"));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            // Your error handling here!
        }
    }

    private static String makeXmlFileName(String username1, String username2) 
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.reset();
        String key;
        if (username1.compareTo(username2) > 0) {
            key = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(md.digest(username2.getBytes("UTF-8")))
                + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(md.digest(username1.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        } else {
            key = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(md.digest(username1.getBytes("UTF-8")))
                + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(md.digest(username2.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        }
        return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(md.digest(key.getBytes("UTF-8"))) + ".xml";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use names as-is? What is the purpose of digesting them? Please edit answer and give your reasoning.

Comment: @Andreas  Noticed, was editing while you commented :)  Does that answer your question?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know you could use the `hashCode()` of the 2 combined Strings to create a unique key. Keep in mind that 2 different conversations can have the same sender and receiver names.

Comment: `hashCode()` is not guaranteed to return unique values for different input.

Comment: I didn't say that. Hence my second sentence.

Comment: Your second sentence has nothing to do with my point, which is that two different names *may* return the same hashcode, e.g. there is *no guarantee* that "John" and "Robert" don't have the same hashcode. Sure, those two in particular don't, but you have no guarantee that all person names will return distinct hashcodes.

Comment: Proof: "Markest" and "Thayer" both have hashcode `953e8b79`.

Comment: My bad, I didn't know. Couldn't he overrde the method and make sure they generate a unique hashCode? HashCodes are used for creating keys after all.

Comment: Hashcodes are certainly **not** used for creating keys. Where did you get that idea? See javadoc of [`hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29): *It is **not** required that if two objects are unequal according to the `equals(java.lang.Object)` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.*

Comment: Doesn't HashMap use hashCode() for its object keys?

Comment: No, `HashMap` uses the `hashCode()` value for it's internal *buckets*, but collisions are expected to happen. If you want to know more, read about it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), where an entire section is all about [Collision resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution).